# Instaneous readings are not displaying while fetching data from Google Fit API

Tags: java, android, google-fit

I and my team mates are using MI band 3 to record data from Google Fit API. We are using a third party app - 'Notify and Fitness for MI Band' to sync the data. We are unable to get the Instantaneous Heart Rate.

We are using `DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM`, `DataType.AGGREGATE_HEART_RATE_SUMMARY` to get the average highest and lowest heart readings but the Instaneous readings are not showning

```
package com.example.shubchintak;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.Fitness;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.FitnessOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.Bucket;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.DataPoint;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.DataSet;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.DataSource;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.DataType;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.Field;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.Subscription;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.Value;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.request.DataReadRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.request.DataSourcesRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.request.OnDataPointListener;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.request.SensorRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.result.DataReadResponse;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.result.DataReadResult;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.logging.LogWrapper;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import static java.text.DateFormat.getDateInstance;
import static java.text.DateFormat.getTimeInstance;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    private DrawerLayout mdrawerLayoout;

public static final String TAG = "StepCounter";
    private static final int REQUEST_OAUTH_REQUEST_CODE = 0x1001;
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 0x1001;

    static TextView stepsNo;


    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Shubchintak");

        stepsNo=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.main_stat);

        mdrawerLayoout =(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_activity);
        NavigationView navigationView=findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        FitnessOptions fitnessOptions =
                FitnessOptions.builder()
                        .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM)
                        .addDataType(DataType.AGGREGATE_HEART_RATE_SUMMARY)
                        .build();

        if (!GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this), fitnessOptions)) {
            GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    REQUEST_OAUTH_REQUEST_CODE,
                    GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this),
                    fitnessOptions);
        } else {
            subscribe();
        }
        if (!checkPermissions()) {
            requestPermissions();
        } else {

        }


        mHandler = new Handler();
        startRepeatingTask();

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mdrawerLayoout,mToolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        mdrawerLayoout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

    }
    private boolean checkPermissions() {
        int permissionState = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        int permissionState1 = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.BODY_SENSORS);
        return permissionState == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && permissionState1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    private void requestPermissions() {
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.BODY_SENSORS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Permission is not granted
            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.BODY_SENSORS)) {
                // Show an explanation to the user asynchronously -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
            } else {
                // No explanation needed; request the permission
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.BODY_SENSORS},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

                // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
                // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                // result of the request.
            }
        } else {
            // Permission has already been granted
        }
    }



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_OAUTH_REQUEST_CODE) {
            subscribe();
        }
    }
}

    public void subscribe() {
        // To create a subscription, invoke the Recording API. As soon as the subscription is
        // active, fitness data will start recording.
        Fitness.getRecordingClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
                .subscribe(DataType.AGGREGATE_HEART_RATE_SUMMARY)
                .addOnCompleteListener(
                        new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Log.i(TAG, "Successfully subscribed!");
                                } else {
                                    Log.w(TAG, "There was a problem subscribing.", task.getException());
                                }
                            }
                        });
    }


    public static DataReadRequest queryFitnessData() {
        // [START build_read_data_request]
        // Setting a start and end date using a range of 1 week before this moment.
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date now = new Date();
        cal.setTime(now);
        long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -1);
        long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

        java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = getDateInstance();
        Log.i(TAG, "Range Start: " + dateFormat.format(startTime));
        Log.i(TAG, "Range End: " + dateFormat.format(endTime));

        DataReadRequest readRequest =
                new DataReadRequest.Builder()
                        // The data request can specify multiple data types to return, effectively
                        // combining multiple data queries into one call.
                        // In this example, it's very unlikely that the request is for several hundred
                        // datapoints each consisting of a few steps and a timestamp.  The more likely
                        // scenario is wanting to see how many steps were walked per day, for 7 days.
                        .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM, DataType.AGGREGATE_HEART_RATE_SUMMARY)                        // Analogous to a "Group By" in SQL, defines how data should be aggregated.
                        // bucketByTime allows for a time span, whereas bucketBySession would allow
                        // bucketing by "sessions", which would need to be defined in code.
                        .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                        .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        .build();
        // [END build_read_data_request]

        return readRequest;
    }
    private void readData() {
        DataReadRequest readRequest = queryFitnessData();

        Fitness.getHistoryClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
                .readData(readRequest)
                .addOnSuccessListener(
                        new OnSuccessListener<DataReadResponse>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(DataReadResponse  dataReadResponse) {
                                printData(dataReadResponse);
                            }
                        })
                .addOnFailureListener(
                        new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Log.w(TAG, "There was a problem getting the step count.", e);
                            }
                        });
    }
    public static void printData(DataReadResponse dataReadResult) {
        // [START parse_read_data_result]
        // If the DataReadRequest object specified aggregated data, dataReadResult will be returned
        // as buckets containing DataSets, instead of just DataSets.
        if (dataReadResult.getBuckets().size() > 0) {
            Log.i(
                    TAG, "Number of returned buckets of DataSets is: " + dataReadResult.getBuckets().size());
            for (Bucket bucket : dataReadResult.getBuckets()) {
                List<DataSet> dataSets = bucket.getDataSets();
                for (DataSet dataSet : dataSets) {
                    dumpDataSet(dataSet);
                }
            }
        } else if (dataReadResult.getDataSets().size() > 0) {
            Log.i(
                    TAG, "Number of returned buckets of DataSets is:ajsbdajsb " );
            }

        // [END parse_read_data_result]
    }

    private static void dumpDataSet(DataSet dataSet) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Data returned for Data type: " + dataSet.getDataType().getName());
        DateFormat dateFormat = getTimeInstance();

        for (DataPoint dp : dataSet.getDataPoints()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Data point:");
            Log.i(TAG, "\tType: " + dp.getDataType().getName());
            Log.i(TAG, "\tStart: " + dateFormat.format(dp.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
            Log.i(TAG, "\tEnd: " + dateFormat.format(dp.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
            for (Field field : dp.getDataType().getFields()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "\tField: " + field.getName() + " Value: " + dp.getValue(field));
                if(field.getName().equals("average")){
                    stepsNo.setText(dp.getValue(field).toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }


 @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_logout:
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                sendToStart();
                break;
            case R.id.action_read_data:
                Log.i(TAG, "Entered method read data");
                readData();
                break;
        }
        mdrawerLayoout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mdrawerLayoout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            mdrawerLayoout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if(currentUser == null){

//            sendToStart();

        }

    }
    private void sendToStart() {

        Intent startIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StartActivity.class);
        startActivity(startIntent);
        finish();

    }
    private int mInterval = 3000; // 5 seconds by default, can be changed later
    private Handler mHandler;


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        stopRepeatingTask();
    }

    Runnable mStatusChecker = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                readData(); //this function can change value of mInterval.
            } finally {
                // 100% guarantee that this always happens, even if
                // your update method throws an exception
                mHandler.postDelayed(mStatusChecker, mInterval);
            }
        }
    };

    void startRepeatingTask() {
        mStatusChecker.run();
    }

    void stopRepeatingTask() {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mStatusChecker);
    }

}
```

Expected solution : to display the instaneous data

Answer (score 0):

```java
        Fitness.getRecordingClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
                .subscribe(DataType.AGGREGATE_HEART_RATE_SUMMARY)
```

This won't work; you need to subscribe to `DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM`.

Could you point me to where you're trying to read instantaneous heart rate? I couldn't see it in the code.